# What effect does completely destroying your city have?

Tags: simcity-2013

Say you have gotten a city started and you hate it. You have enough money to start a new one, all bonds free, etc.

What effects would it have if I completely flattened everything? Utilities, buildings, zones, town hall, everything. Would it be like starting fresh, or would there be something "left"? Like angry people caused by me destroying everything or whatever?

Comment: Try it and tell us.  Be careful about bulldozing near your entryway.  There are reports of certain maps where you can bulldoze that to the point of being unable to reconnect to the outside.  Also - I recommend applying the bulldozer to the streets instead of the buildings.  Without streets, the buildings (and traffic and people) go away too.

Comment: Though you might find yourself with some homeless people at the entrance of the highway, they will quickly disappear once you start rebuilding. Bulldozing everything (as mentioned in the previous comment, aim for the roads, but I would add to hold Ctrl pressed to make it 10x faster) is the only way to restart a city withing restarting a new region. Note, however, that it will not erase pollution and it will not refill your resources (if you drilled oil, it won't come back). If you wait long enough without anything on your map, all the pollution will eventually disappear.

Comment: Power off all services (fire/police/hospitals) etc before bulldozing them otherwise you are left w/ zombie entities left in the system.

Answer (score 3):

My wife actually decided to try this last night... she had a couple hundred grand and was not pleased with her initial zoning decisions. She paused the time, and flattened the city, leaving only a few high density streets (not avenues), her fully upgraded sewage treatment plant, and a well upgraded water treatment plant.
She then turned the remaining plants off, and placed trees over all of the polluted areas.
She put it in Cheetah speed, and waited for the population to disipate.

When the pollution faded to what she deemed to be an acceptable level, she began re-zoning the city and placing services according to her master plan. The population exploded rather quicky, and the leftover roads were immediately supporting brand new high density buildings...

As a note - My connected city took about half of her population when she did this.

Comment: I do this to abandoned cities on public regions.  Taxes to 20%. Go to work. Get home and build a masterpiece.